# Comparing two .jars with different obfuscation

Tags: java, comparison, byte, obfuscation, bytecode

I need to compare to jar files that have many of the same classes but with different names.

Lets say you are looking for a class that contains this:

```
public class AStar {
    private int verbose = 0;
    private int maxSteps = -1;
    private int numSearchSteps;
    public ISearchNode bestNodeAfterSearch;
```

etc..., but it's obfuscated into

```
public class ard {
    private int fas = 0;
    private int asd = -1;
    private int ags;
    public ars arser;
```

and you have to compare the first file against 100 of others to find this one. 
My guess was a byte code comparison, but I can't find a tool for it or a method to compare all files against each other in the two jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in the past, but the problem is that generally a lot of manual work is also required to determine the type of information that is preserved, and which libraries to compare it with.

For example, in one case, I found that the obfuscated Jar had added a method to a library class which threw off the comparison until I found and accounted for it. Another common problem is that obfuscators will remove unused methods and interfaces and sometimes add obfuscator-specific methods.

In order to get good results, you can't just consider individual classes. You need to match up inheritance hierarchies, interfaces, and cross references between the classes in order to unambiguously match most classes, and even then it isn't always successful.

Luckily, they almost never reorder or change the signatures of the fields and methods. Otherwise it would be extremely difficult to collect enough information to unambiguously match up the classes. As it is, there are often classes with the exact same set of methods and inheritance (for example two classes that implement the same interface). If you're lucky, you'll be able to infer it by matching references from a third class, but this isn't always possible.

Anyway, I can send you my code if you want. It's designed for the recognition of open source libraries included in an obfuscated app, but it could probably be adapted to match two obfuscated apps as well.

Comment: That would be great for future updates, I just got found all the methods I edited and the classes now all that is needed is a way to edit the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pull this off with [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/index.html). It has pretty good documentation, and quite some samples.

You build an internal model from the types and values, and then compare and spit out the identical classes.

If it was you who obfuscated it, you should be able to get the mappings though...

Comment: It wasn't me who obfuscated it. The developers allow you too modify it, but they don't release the source >_>. And what do you mean by an internal model?

Comment: Just somehow store the information you read, and afterwards compare it. Why do you need it?

Comment: I would like to update my modification because the people that work on making a decompiler said it would take about two to three weeks for it to be updated and all I really need is three or so classes edited.

Comment: If you are looking for a decompiler try [JDGui](http://jd.benow.ca/). It never failed for me...

Comment: I already have it decompiled, its the fact of going through about 1780 files to find the three I need.

Comment: Then, try to compare them with ASM. It will take some time to get used to their model, but afterwards you can use it for a lot of interesting problems.

Comment: Is there a tool to compare one file to multiple by any chance?

Comment: @user2563088 Which decompiler are you using? For highly obfuscated code, I think the Krakatau Decompiler works much better (disclaimer: I wrote it)

Comment: @Antimony: Either you have a very high self-esteem, or it must be really good... Though he said he did decompile it, he just is to lazy to look through 1780 files...

Comment: @StackOverflowException Well for one thing, there are very few decompilers that are designed to deal with obfuscation at all. Besides Krakatau, the only major one I know of is Dava. And based on the Dava papers, I think Krakatau is generally more sophisticated and robust, though Dava does have a few syntactic sugar things that Krakatau doesn't do yet. But if you don't beleive me, you can try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, determining whether two arbitrary programs do the same thing for all inputs is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) (reducible to the halting problem).

For the following, I'll assume the obfuscation doesn't mess with the class structure: it will only rename fields, methods and classes and possibly obfuscate bytecode.

Let's say you're looking for an obfuscated class that's equivalent to some class `C`. Here are some searches you could perform, in increasing order of difficulty:

1. Find all classes with the exact same number of fields and methods as `C` has.
2. For each obfuscated class, compute the set of field types it contains (but, for simplicity, don't include types that point to other obfuscated classes). All classes where this set of field types is not a subset of the field types of `C` can be filtered out.
3. Do the same for method signatures.
4. You could go further but it could get pretty complicated.

In the end, what works best depends on what specific things the obfuscator does and does not try to hide.

[ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) is a good library for parsing and processing `.class` files.

Answer (score 0):

If the obfuscation changed *only* variable names, and not variable order or any of the compiler-generated bytecode, you should be able to do this with ASM or Javassist or other bytecode library.  In fact, the list below can be done using regular Java reflection.

Two class files would be candidates for equality if:

1. They have the same number of methods
2. There is a 1-to-1 mapping between the parameter signatures of the methods in class A and class B
3. The matching method also match in terms of flags (private/public, static, abstract, etc.)

That would be a pretty good match.  Beyond that and you might have to get into the details of the byte code.  The byte code should be similar, but references to the Const Pool might be scrambled.  You would have to decipher those.  For example one class might `ldc #12` and the other might `ldc #34`; if it turns out that #12 in class A is the same as #34 in class B, they match (at least for that).

If the obfuscator rewires the order of parameters on private methods, it might be really hard to detect a match easily.  Still, maybe all you need to do is to narrow it down to a reasonable number of candidates, so applying the list above to public and protected methods might be all you need.

Comment: Thanks, sadly it's an updated version, so there are changed, but I currently manually mapping them out since I found the class the runs everything. I already mapped 2 of the 3 classes I needed. I am also mapping any other I can find to help out other modders.

Comment: Checking the number of methods is problematic since obfuscations usually remove unused methods.

Comment: @Antimony I did not expect that... I would hope that _developers_ would remove unused methods. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use Beyond Compare to compare jar files:

http://www.scootersoftware.com/

You may have some luck using their additional file formats to compare .class files (decompiled)

http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformats_win